# Concept of pleasure in pedagogy in the time of Rabelais

Tags: french-language, francois-rabelais

I am currently writing a paper with 'games' as a subject. One of the axes I am working on deals with games contributing to pleasure in pedagogy, and I intend to use Rabelais' concept mentioned in *Gargantua* as an example.

However, due to the burlesque nature of this work, I cannot clearly explain why Rabelais chose games, except for the fact that it is entertaining. Hence my question: how did 16th-century humanists see the concepts of games and pleasure in the context of pedagogy? I am particularly interested in answers based on 16th-century humanist literature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for article references.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I think this is a fine question. The article references are for the purpose of understanding the background to the book

Comment: The question is too broad, I think. Per [this](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/references-on-specific-pieces-of-literature), it'd be fine when asking for references on a very particular point in a specific book.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Is pleasure in pedagogy not particular enough?